# Is it possible to remove space in histogram with many bins?

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I am plotting a histogram with many bins (1000+).  Code is below:

```
library(tidyverse)
xx=rpois(1000,lambda = 40)
y=density(xx,n=1000,from=0)

ggplot(data.frame(x = y$x, y = y$y), aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_histogram(stat='identity',aes(fill=y))
```

[image]

As you can see, it is adding unwanted spacing in between my bars (I would like a seamless gradient).  Is there a way to remove these spaces?  For reference, I am aware of the way to use `geom_segment` to achieve these results so for right now I am only interested in fixing the histogram issue (if possible).  Setting `color=y` inside the `aes` works but my larger goal here is a hacky code that lets me essentially graph two density curves with two completely separate gradients (thus I need to save my `geom_segment` and `color` for the other density curve).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Adding a `width=` statement (this varies depending on your scale) that forces the bars to overlap works.  It does give me a warning message `position_stack requires non-overlapping x intervals` but it still plots without the spaces.  My exmaple below:

```
library(tidyverse)
xx=rpois(1000,lambda = 40)
y=density(xx,n=2000,from=0)

ggplot(data.frame(x = y$x, y = y$y), aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_histogram(stat='identity',color=NA,aes(fill=y),width=0.1) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]