# How to remove space between bins in histogram

Tags: r, histogram

Apparently, `hist` separates bins by spaces if the length of the plotted vector exceeds 2,000 values:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
hist(sample(1:10, 2000, replace = T), main = "", col = "grey")
hist(sample(1:10, 2100, replace = T), main = "", col = "grey")
```

[image]

How can the spaces be removed/avoided if the vector plotted contains more than 2000 values?

Comment: This would help. [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49119569/is-it-possible-to-remove-space-in-histogram-with-many-bins)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't add spaces; it adds bins. Keep `breaks = 9` and it works as before:

```r
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
hist(sample(1:10, 2000, replace = T), main = "", col = "grey")
hist(sample(1:10, 2100, replace = T), main = "", col = "grey", breaks = 9)
```

[image]

The reason for the jump is that `hist`'s default method for calculating breaks is `nclass.Sturges(x)` where `x` is your vector. This simple function is just `ceiling(log2(length(x)) + 1)`. In your case, the transition will occur if the vector is longer than 2048, when calculated bins jumps from 12 to 13:

```
hist(sample(1:10, 2048, replace = T), main = "", col = "grey")
hist(sample(1:10, 2049, replace = T), main = "", col = "grey")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-07-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>